# I can not figure out this Error parsing XML: no element found

Tags: xml, parsing

The last line of code is where I am getting the Parsing XML error. I believe it is also what is causing my 5 other errors. I am new to coding so I will do my best to provide the information needed to help address this issue.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button android:id="@+id/btnStart" android:layout_width="wrap_content"android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Start AsyncTask"></Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/btnSend" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Send Message"></Button>
<TextView android:id="@+id/textStatus" android:textSize="24sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Status Goes Here"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've noticed.

1. There is no end tag for the `TextView` element.
2. In the first `Button` element, there is no space between the attributes `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`.

Comment: was having thos problem. followed 17 other suggestions before seeing this comment and deciding to check my XML syntax. i was missing a closing tag. this answer helped me.